# The name DnsClient does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

I have created a C# console application using visual studio 2010.

We are migrating our hosted sites a new server, and I have been set the task of checking the domains on the new server map to the same place as the domains on the old server.

I have been told do so using the following example:

https://docs.ar-soft.de/arsoft.tools.net/#DNS%20Client.html

This is all pretty new to me and I am on the edge of my understanding, but I just about understand what I need to do.

My problem is, when I add the following line of code:

```
DnsMessage dnsMessage = DnsClient.Default.Resolve("www.example.com", RecordType.A);
```

It is not recognising either the

```
DnsMessage
```

OR

```
DnsClient
```

As far as I can understand, both of these are in:

```
using System.Net;
```

Which is present on the page.

So what can I do to make this piece of code work?

This makes me think I am using the wrong type of project otherwise I cannot understand why it does not recognise these commands?

This brings me to a related side note. It seems to me I am missing something about C#, because I sometimes come across bits of code that are not recognised at all in the project I amusing, for example in some web applications I just cannot get a message box to appear, as again it does not seem to be recognised in the environment I am working in.

It seems that not all C# code can be run in all C# applications, so if this is the case, how can I tell what can be run and where?

Comment: There's a `System.Net.Dns` class, but no `System.Net.DnsClient` as far as I can see...

Comment: MessageBox is a WinForms control. You'll need to read up on ASP.NET and familiarize yourself with the available web controls if you want to work with web applications.

Comment: Were you trying to use this obsoleted method? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.resolve(v=vs.110).aspx If you notice at the bottom of the page, it shows what frameworks it is supported by.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't built in.  Per your documentation link, it's a 3rd party library called `ARSoft.Tools.Net`.  You can install from [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/ARSoft.Tools.Net):

```
Install-Package ARSoft.Tools.Net
```

You could also download the binaries from the project's [codeplex site](https://arsofttoolsnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/615056)

Comment: I have downloaded the library, but how do I actually include it in my project, so I can use the code in it?

Comment: The easiest way is to install via NuGet.  If you have the binaries and want to do this manually, you'd need to add a reference in your project via `Add Reference...`.

Comment: I think it is added, I installed NuGet and then used the pacakage manager console, where it said I have successfully downloaded it. But the code is not recognised yet, so I am obviously missing something

Comment: You'd at least need to add `using ARSoft.Tools.Net.Dns;` at the top.

Comment: I have tried that but it cannot find it. I will work it out. Thank youf ro your help I appreciate it.